# Is it posible to relaunch my program after it exits?

Tags: c++

Is it posible to relaunch my program after it exits? It's like setting a timer to launch my program, but it does exit each time.

Here is pseudocode:

```
int main()
{
   MyFunc();  
   exit();
   RestartMeEveryHour();
}
```

Comment: Once you call the exit function cleanup operations are performed, don't call it in the first place (or manage it externally)

Comment: Don't try to manage periodic startup in your own program. Use an external OS scheduler service to do that. Both Windows and Linux come with built-in scheduling services.

Comment: agree with Andy, this is the best way. just make sure the command env. settings. The cron/scheduler will not get the same env as you start your program with your user account.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There may be two different options:

1. Schedule execution of your program with the operating system. You can do this manually or programmatically through the API. This way may not be portable between different operating systems.
2. Write an additional program that stays in the background and which will start your first program periodically.

Comment: 1. How can I "programmatically through the API"? Is there any sample code? 2. Does "staying in the background" means program is invisible from task manager?

Comment: About option 1: I was trying to use system("at 12.00 c:\\test.exe") but win7 needs administrative accounts to do at command. Anyway I can bypass that?

Answer (score 1):

Besides using `cron` (in Unix/Linux/OSX) or `scheduler` (Windows), you can of course do:

```
int main()
{
    for(;;)
    {
       MyFunc();
       sleepOneHour();
    }
}
```

Comment: for (;;) is kidding him, :)

Comment: It's how I (nearly) always write forever loops... ;)

Comment: the forever loop depends on MyFunc() running stably forever.

Comment: Well, if `MyFunc` is not stable, then the two other solutions are obviously better - but then any problem in `MyFunc` should probably be fixed, rather than anything else [assuming we're talking about something that can be reliably done in the first place - if we're testing code that may have bugs, for example, then that's a different matter]

Comment: @MatsPetersson Your way never ends the program, doesn't it? I need my program exit and then self-start again and again.

Comment: Why do you need that? If the program is sleeping, it will consume no resources in the system, aside from a little bit of memory for the process itself - everything else can, if the memory is needed for something else be swapped out to disk.

Comment: @MatsPetersson Well.. I need the program to be invisible form task manager. This exit-restart-function seems to be alternative option.

Comment: So, use the Scheduler... But it will of course be listed in the Scheduler list in that case, so if you are after writing spyware, I'm not sure you're much better off that way.